# How to restart auto-dismissing <b-alert>?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have created a vuejs2 component that I want to do the following:

- Receive an "event" using $on and display a `<b-alert>` for 6 seconds.
- When the same "event" message is received restart the b-alert timeout
- Display multiple `<b-alert>` if there are different messages received

This is what I've tried:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-alert
      v-for="message in bannerMessages"
      :key="message.messageId"
      :show="message.secondsLeft"
      :variant="message.level"
      dismissible
      fade
      @dismissed="bannerMessageDismissed(message)"
      @dismiss-count-down="bannerCountDown(message)"
    >
      {{ message.message }}
    </b-alert>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventBus from "@/eventBus"

export default {
  name: "EventBusNotifications",
  data() {
    return {
      bannerMessages: []
    };
  },

  methods: {
    showMessage(message) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.bannerMessages.length; i++) {
        if (this.bannerMessages[i].message === message.message) {
          this.bannerMessages[i].secondsLeft = 6;
          return;
        }
      }
         
      this.bannerMessages.push({
        ...message,
        messageId: Date.now() + `-${message.message}`,
        secondsLeft: 6,
      });
    },

    bannerMessageDismissed(message) {
      const index = this.bannerMessages.indexOf(message);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.bannerMessages.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    bannerCountDown(message) {
      const index = this.bannerMessages.indexOf(message);
      console.log(index);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.bannerMessages[index].secondsLeft -= 1;

        if (this.bannerMessages[index].secondsLeft === 0) {
          this.bannerMessages.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    EventBus.$on("notification", this.showMessage);
  },

  destroyed() {
    EventBus.$off("notification", this.showMessage);
  },
};
</script>
```

And here is the eventBus file:

```
import Vue from "vue";
const EventBus = new Vue();
export default EventBus;
```

THen, to use it, in any vue.js component or page,  `import EventBus from "@/eventBus"` and then send an `$emit` like this:

`EventBus.$emit("notification", { level: "warning", message: "This is the message", secondsLeft: 5});`

The idea here is to reset the number of seconds on the `<b-alert>` if a matching message came in, but instead the message only appears very briefly (less than half a second). The `bannerCountDown()` method gets called rapidly instead of every second.

What would be the best approach to making a "restart-able" `<b-alert>`?

Comment: What you posted is not enough to create a *runnable* [mcve]. Consider providing one. Note codesandbox allows [importing](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) local projects via CLI. Ideally you should only provide the minimal needed to repro, not the entire project.

Comment: @tao I have not included the entire project here. This is two files in a hundred file project. All of the content here is required to reproduce...with the exception of the actual JavaScript call to create the alert.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `v-model/show` implementation in `<b-alert>` was not designed for your use-case. The `dismiss-count-down` is emitted on any component `update`.

In your case, this creates a loop which brings the counter down immediately, hiding the alert (because you're mutating the objects in the `dismiss-count-down`, thus triggering another emit). The alerts are only visible because they have `fade`. Without it, they'd be removed on `$nextTick`, so they'd probably not be visible for the human eye.

---

The proper way to circumvent this issue would be to keep counters outside of the component and not rely on the component's counter at all, using some form of `debounce`. You'll need this solution if you want to display the counter values.

If you only want to reset the counter, without actually displaying its value in real time, here's a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-tdd-dpt4st?file=/App.vue), reusing most of your existing logic. I moved the timers in an external object to avoiding additional updates on `<b-alert>`s.

The key to why the above works is I'm not replacing the `timers` object when I'm changing a timer. if I replaced it (e.g: in `tick` i'd do:

```js
this.timers = { ...this.timers, [message]: this.timers[message] - 1 }
```

it would behave exactly like yours.